# Gradle - Ошибка при добавлении библиотеки

Tags: gradle

На код:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.sevgu.myphone"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Ошибка:

> Error:(5, 0) Gradle: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>
> > Could not find method compile() for arguments [org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0] on object of type
> >     org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Answer (score 1):

Внутри замыкания `dependencies` в `buildscript` следует использовать `classpath` вместо `compile`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, вот этот блок

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.2.0'
    }
}
```

должен быть в грэдле уровня приложения, а не модуля